# Insert value to an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have the following array

```
$block = array(
          **********,
          *****,
          **********,
          ***,
          ********);
```

Assuming max length of each array would be 10

I'm trying to insert new value in that array so my output would be as follows:

```
**********
*****00000
**********
***0000000
********00
```

So the following are my codes:

```
foreach($block as $key=>$newblock)
{
    $counter = 10 - strlen($newblock); 
    if ($counter > 0)
    {
      for($x=0; $x < $counter; $x++)
      {
          $block[$key] = implode("0",$newblock);
      }
    }
}

foreach($block as $x)
{
    print $x;
}
```

The codes seems not working..

Comment: try $block[$key].='0' instead of implode in loop, can you share current output?

Comment: if i assign $block[$key] = '0', it will replace the '*' to '0' instead add '0' value at the end of the array

Comment: its not ='0' its .='0' there is '.' operator to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$block = array(
          '**********',
          '*****',
          '**********',
          '***',
          '********');

foreach($block as $key=>$newblock)
{
    $counter = 10 - strlen($newblock); 
    if ($counter > 0)
      for($x=0; $x < $counter; $x++)
          $block[$key] .= "0";
}

foreach($block as $x)
    print $x."<br/>";
?>
```

Output

```
**********
*****00000
**********
***0000000
********00
```

Comment: Great that I could help, welcome to stackoverflow @Julie

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, use function `str_pad($input,$length,$pad_string)` read more about [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
<?php 
$block = array('**********','*****','**********','***','********'); 
foreach($block as $key=>$val)
{
    echo str_pad($val,10,"0");
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

This will Output :

```
**********
*****00000
**********
***0000000
********00
```